# ASP.NET Core VS2015 upgrade issue

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How to get this project.json working in vs2015.
I've downloaded the latest runtime and sdk but trying to update the packages but can't get it to work to get the correct packages.

After trying several configs, reinstalling packages I don't know which number combinations 1.0 1.1.0 1.0.3 1.1.0-preview etc.. I should try to get the packages working...

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.1"
  },
  "userSecretsId": ":-)"
}
```

Comment: You do know that project.json is no longer supported right? You need to install VS2017 and that will automatically upgrade your project to csproj format.

Comment: nope I just openend VS2015 and did upgrade of packages etc... no idea. can't switch to VS2015 right now so might need some help...

Comment: I really don't think you're going to get much help from anyone though, nobody cares about project.json any more.

Comment: so you are actually saying that doing development in VS2015 for asp.net core is not supported anymore. Think I'm going to move back to good old ASP.NET MVC and drop the "core".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.I would strongly recommend using VS2017 though. It will install alongside 2015.